# How can I recover files?

Tags: data-recovery

In my 21.10 impish Linux partition I was working on all kinds of things at the same time and got side tracked by jammy jellyfish. Who doesn't? Things these days seem to run so seamlessly that I thought I would try to update while working. Yea that was as dumb as it sounds. So I got a while screen that said oops something went wrong.
I shut down the PC and of course the ubuntu was so corrupted from the experiment that it wouldn't start.
Off to the windows partition. I downloaded some software that can read the Linux files on the Linux partition but, lost of the folders are empty in that Linux partition. Why? and how do I recover the data that's still in that partition before wiping it and starting over the right way.
All the file tree is there the user the folders everything but the files in the folders is there. I have not run a recovery on the partition for fears of loosing the data. I have only tried to access the folders through windows 10 and a new ubuntu ssd. Neither the Linux drive nor the windows partition can read everything in my 21.10 partition.

Comment: First off, don't use Windows 'recovery' tools. Windows... is bad at reading ext4 (Ubuntu) partitions. Instead, use a Ubuntu live CD (boot to the installer USB stick, do Try Ubuntu), and from there you can try to recover data. Note that these USB sticks aren't persistent, so any data you copy to the USB drive will get deleted upon reboot.

Comment: I would suggest Clonezilla to clone the partition to somewhere. unfortunately Clonezilla does not have a menu for selecting individual files, but there are ways to 'unzip' it to somewhere you can access as normal files.